# Why is there user-ownership in Linux? Aren't group/other file permissions enough?

Tags: linux, file-permissions

I think I rather understand how file permissions work in linux. However, I don't really understand why they are split into three levels and not into two: can anyone explain the rationale for why a single user can own a file? Isn't having group/other permissions enough? With your answer, I'd be happy if you reference to discussions I can read on this topic.

Comment: [Is there a reason why 'owner' permissions exist? Aren't group permissions enough?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/55533)

Answer (score 3):

Surely this is sort of self evident. If I create a file on a multiuser machine, which I want kept private, then I want to be able to specify that in the permissions. This is especially important with user specific data such as private keys.

Comment: It also specifies your _own_ relationship to the file: you can make a file read only if you don't want to change it accidentally (although this doesn't prevent deletion). Or chmod 000 to make it unreadable (mostly useless, except for debugging)

Answer (score 0):

This is especially important if there are isn’t a specific group for each user (as there is today on, say, Debian, where a group userx is created when userx is created). Furthermore, it allows to give access to both a specific user, who may then give access to another group of which he is not necessarily a member without having to add himself to that group, something that can only be done by root.